# Manipulating Many Text Files In a Directory Using Python

Tags: python, string, loops, directory, text-files

I'm using python 3.6.1.
I have a directory filled with thousands of text files.

I want to remove the first 2 lines in each text files, without making a new copy of each text files.

Also, I want to remove the last line in each file if they contain a certain "keyword", if not, then the last line is not removed and still there.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(I assumed text files have at least 3 lines):

```
import glob

path = r"./"                                #Type your PATH here or run the script in your files' directory                 
filenames = glob.glob(path + "*.txt")          
keyword = "keyword"

for file in filenames:
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines = lines[2:]                       #Delete first and second line
    if keyword in lines[len(lines) - 1]:
        lines = lines[:-1]                  #Delete last line if necessary
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the os library will do.

```
    import os
    import re

    path = r"<directory>"

    #now you could print everything inside the directory
    print(os.listdir(path))

    #to print each item separately
    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        #the roots will select all the roots, dirs will select the directories 
        #inside your directory and files will select only the files inside 
        #your directory

        #to get the files
        for file in files:
            #you can print all filenames for test purpose
            print("File = %s", file)

            #now you have the string names of all files, all that is left to do 
            #is parse them using regular expressions.

            parts = re.split("\.",file)
            #this will spit the string after the period 
            #the parts variable will now have two parts, first part containing 
            #the file name and the second part containing the file extension.

            if(parts[1]=="txt"):
                f = open(file,"w")
                #now you can do whatever you want with the file
```

Hope this works out for you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the python `os module` and perform the operation on each text file in the directory:

```
import os

path = "Your directory path"
for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
                lines = open(file).readlines()
                open(file, 'w').writelines(lines[2:])
                if keyword in lines:
                        open(file, 'w').writelines(lines[:-1])
```